# Delay all emails I send in a specific time span

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, delay

The company I work for has a "no email between 10 and 12" policy as a way to give everybody 2 hours to focus on their tasks without being disturbed. In this time span, we are supposed to avoid sending emails to each other (except for emergencies).

We're using Outlook 2010.

I'd like to be able to put together some form of rule that delays every email I send during this period so I can still make my requests or deliver reports, and have them sit in my outbox until the "no email period" is finished. This way, I could get things out of my head without forgetting to deliver them.

Is that possible?

(sorry if this has been asked, couldn't find it)

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. How do you prevent people from outside the company, who are unaware of your policy, from sending messages during the "no e-mail period"? If you want people to be able to focus from ten to noon, it makes more sense to expect the recipient to turn off their e-mail program, or at least the notification feature. Putting that burden on senders, many of which you have no control over, doesn't scale well.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge you cannot automate this, but you can set a delay per email.

To do this in outlook 2016, create a new email, go to the options tab, and press the button Delay delivery.

Here you can specify a date and time, and the server will then hold the email and send it at the given moment.

Do note that the email does not arrive before that date to the sender, but a server admin could still see in the logs that you sent the mail before. However, I'm pretty sure that with the reason you want this, your company will not bash you, and they will most likely not find out unless you forget to do this and send the email too soon afterall.

If this really is not an option for you, then create the email and instead of hitting send, press the close button. It will ask you if you want to save the email. Hit yes, and the email will be saved to your drafts folder. Once you are allowed to send emails again, you go to the drafts folder, click each email and hit send on it to send it away.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of the delay that you can apply to each email. But as you supposed, I was looking for a way to automate it.

The logs showing my emails on hold isn't a problem, and I bet I'll have to rely on that option until I find a better solution.

Thank you for your response.

Comment: It is also possible to put your outlook in offline mode. Any mails going out will also be queued then, but I don't think you can automate that either.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible via Outlook native options/settings. If you can accept the offline mode option as LPChip suggested, you may have a look at the following article, which stated that we can use a script to achieve it:

[How to Auto Set Outlook Online or Offline Based on Your Working Hours](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/auto-set-outlook-online-offline-based-working-hours/)